# Getting Errors while starting hbase service

Tags: java, hbase

I  installed hbase-2.4.17  hbase-2.4.17-bin.tar.gz (standalone),when i start the hbase instance getting errors

./start-hbase.sh
ERROR: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.372.b07-1.el7_9.x86_64/bin/java is not executable.
/root/hbase/hbase-2.4.17/bin/hbase: line 805: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.372.b07-1.el7_9.x86_64/bin/java: No such file or directory
ERROR: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.372.b07-1.el7_9.x86_64/bin/java is not executable.
/root/hbase/hbase-2.4.17/bin/hbase: line 805: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.372.b07-1.el7_9.x86_64/bin/java: No such file or directory
running master, logging to /root/hbase/hbase-2.4.17/bin/../logs/hbase-root-master-sgpllab2111.out
/root/hbase/hbase-2.4.17/bin/hbase-daemon.sh: line 92: kill: (4425) - No such process

cutable.
/root/hbase/hbase-2.4.17/bin/../bin/hbase: line 805: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.372.b07-1.el7_9.x86_64/bin/java: No such file or directory
: running regionserver, logging to /root/hbase/hbase-2.4.17/bin/../logs/hbase-root-regionserver-sgpllab2111.out
: /root/hbase/hbase-2.4.17/bin/hbase-daemon.sh: line 92: kill: (4535) - No such process
:
: cutable.
: /root/hbase/hbase-2.4.17/bin/../bin/hbase: line 805: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.372.b07-1.el7_9.x86_64/bin/java: No such file or directory

Comment: `ls -l /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.372.b07-1.el7_9.x86_64/bin/java`. Does it exist? Also, not good to install it in `/root`. Use `/opt` if available, or `/usr/share`

Comment: ls -l /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.372.b07-1.el7_9.x86_64/bin/java
ls: cannot access /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.372.b07-1.el7_9.x86_64/bin/java: No such file or directory

Comment: So somehow, hbase is picking up a bogus JDK. I would suggest, as a preliminary, to set `JAVA_HOME` to your *actual* jdk install directory. You can find out what that is by `readlink -f "$(which javac)"` and looking at the location of `javac`